# Processes accessing USB device freeze and become uninteruptible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, filesystems, ntfs-3g

I have a program that is supposed to write a large number of files onto an external USB-3 drive, with NTFS filesystem. There seems to be some problem with this: at first it periodically freezes for some minutes, then it freezes permanently.

The process becomes uninterruptible. See screenshot: [image: system monitor].

The waiting channel is "read_descriptor". All of these processes (tried launching it multiple times), have openned the file /sys/.../usb4/descriptors.

In this state it seems all commands that access the USB device freeze. Including:

- `lsusb`
- `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices`
- USB Reset scripts which call `/sys/..../unbind`

After I tried to unmount the partition, after using `umount --force` (possibly also other commands, not sure exactly anymore), it did unmount, and no longer appears when calling `mount`. However in the *Disks* application, it still appears as "Unmounting Filesystem".

Also the disk has a lot of bad sectors (984 already). It is a completely new drive. It seems to get bad sectors when writing to it from Linux.

[image: Disks application]

It there any way to restart the USB subsystem / force the device to be disconnected, without restarting the system? (`update-grub` also blocks, and the default setting of the bootloader menu is wrongly set, so I can't remotely connect after rebooting).

And what could cause this problem with the USB drive?

The system also seemed to have similar problems with another external USB drive (reading slowing down, to less than 1 MB/s).

The system is Ubuntu linux, 16.04.2 LTS, Xenial
on a 64 bit machine

*Update*:

#### lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family H97 Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 740] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
```

---

#### lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
btrfs                 987136  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
ufs                    73728  0
qnx4                   16384  0
hfsplus               106496  0
hfs                    57344  0
minix                  36864  0
ntfs                   98304  0
msdos                  20480  0
jfs                   180224  0
xfs                   970752  0
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               454656  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
binfmt_misc            20480  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
nvidia_uvm            745472  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   544768  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  5
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
mei_me                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
input_leds             16384  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 36864  0
serio_raw              16384  0
tpm_infineon           20480  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
acpi_pad               24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  1
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
uas                    24576  8
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
nvidia_drm             53248  1
nvidia_modeset        778240  4 nvidia_drm
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 nvidia_drm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
nvidia              11931648  63 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
ahci                   36864  3
e1000e                237568  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
fjes                   28672  0
video                  40960  1 asus_wmi
```

Comment: Is the drive an ssd or hdd? You say you think linux writting to it is causing bad sectors which I take to mean you have windows on the same machine and it does not seem to cause the same issue, is that correct?

Comment: it is hdd (LaCie Porsche Design 4TB, Seagate drive). yes on windows it makes bo problems: wrote about 500GB to it, no there was no freezing and no filesystem errors found afterwards

Comment: Very strange. You've functionally eliminated hardware as a possible cause. I can only imagine it's an incompatibility between the kernel modules and the USB host. Can we get an `lspci` to see what USB hosts you have? `lsmod` might be useful as well to see what kernel modules your system is using.

Comment: included it in the post

Comment: It's not showing the xhci (usb 3) module, but it might be compiled into the kernel. What does `lspci -v -s 14.0` show?

Comment: Actually, it's not showing the ehci module either. `lspci -v -s 1d.0`?

Comment: Can you determine if LPM (Link Power Management) is enabled/disabled on these two OS?

Comment: If there were a few big files, you might use "sudo mount -o big_writes /media/<mount_dir> /dev/<device>", which prevents *fuse* from splitting large files, but it may not help  for many small ones. Another option might be mounting using the sync option, forcing writes to finish before starting next. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/297029/automount-with-async-option

Comment: xhci and ehci seemed to be built in. (Showed such a message when tried to disable with `modprobe`)

Comment: Also, isn't there a limit of 2.2TB for NTFS?

Comment: It now causes the same problem in Windows (I/O error when copying with 7zip, and then `diskpart`, and other applications freeze). Not it says "power surge on USB port" or "Device needs more power than port can provide" and doesn't mount anymore. It is a USB-3 drive, with a USB-C connector on the drive itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "waiting channel" is in "read_descriptor" state, it means that the USB channel went into heavy recovery after a fairly serious hardware problem, because the "descriptor stage" occurs only on port reset, and port reset happens only when an unrecoverable transaction error occurs.

The fact that it works under Windows only means that the OS software likely engages some different hardware configuration and controller/PHY parameters.

I strongly suspect that the Link Power Management (LPM) is at fault here. The Linux distribution likely enables all bells and whistles and latest and greatest, while Windows might use so-called Intel-devised "filter driver" to fix some controller deficiencies.

The LPM states U1 and U2 occur on hardware level, so they are likely invisible from software side. To determine if the link goes back and forth into LPM states, you would need a super-speed USB protocol analyzer, Ellisys 280 or Teledyne LeCroy Advisor T3, or some other tool that detect LPM states on Super-Speed link, like this much [less expensive tool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M4QR9C7).

Comment: Are the "bad sectors" likely to be hardware damage, or just logical errors on the filesystem, or misreadings?

Comment: @tmlen, hard to say. The issue is likely in USB interface hanging randomly, but to what extent it can damage the SATA drive, I don't know. You should take the drive out, put it on a normal SATA cable, and test/re-format it thoroughly on a working trusted OS.

Answer (score 0):

This is consistent with what we have seen with USB Flash devices. Stack traces imply that EP0 SETUP requests issued to read descriptors during or immediately following write activity causes an irrecoverable condition.

This is not universal, so it could be yet another case of poor standards compliance by some USB devices. However, it's also possible that the Linux USB mass storage driver has a bug.

Here's a recent protocol analyzer dump of it happening (there is about a gigabyte worth of writes immediately proceeding what's visible here). Within 1 ms of the last write completing there's a descriptor read, after which the device no longer responds to further writes.

[image]

Comment: This has been a bug in linux for what, 30 years now? They really need to fix this.

Comment: Yeah. But clearly nobody who's close enough to this code cares. I tried to look for it, but it wasn't anything obvious that I could find. Someone probably needs to review the entire state transition flow for the USB drivers to find this (presumably) race condition.